# Blob not opening PDF in IE browser, working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, blob

Trying to load one PDF which we are getting from service on an page. It is working fine in chrome, but not loading in IE and Firefox

Code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
       req.open("POST", "url to get blob", true);
       req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       req.responseType = "blob";
       req.onload = function (event) {

               var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

               var file_name = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
               encodeURIComponent(file_name);

               $('.pdf-preview').attr('src',file_name);

                //window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, file_name);

        };
```

Working fine in Chrome but in IE and Firefox i get following error:
Could not open PDF, something keeping PDF from loading.

I was able to download the PDF file by using:

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, file_name);
```

But I want to load the file inside a div not download it. Blob dont work in IE and Firefox?

Comment: Why do you do a POST request exactly? Sounds like all you need here is `$('.pdf-preview').attr('src', "url to get blob")`. Also, `req.response`  is already a Blob. Why `new Blob([req.response])`? `encodeURIComponent(file_name);` does nothing here (luckily). And yes, you can definitely preview pdf in Firefox from BlobURLs, something is wrong in your setup.

Comment: PDF viewing is not a standard HTML / Browser extension, some browsers will have it, some won't.  And some that do have it, might disable it.  If you want to view pdfs in your website it's best doing it yourself.  pdf.js, is good for this -> https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/  Another thing to check, even if your browser does have a pdf viewer built in, it's also possible for the popup blocker to kick in.  Check your browser bar to make sure it's not been blocked.

Comment: @kaiido, I was just testing/ by setting req.response. If you kaneow any working example I can look at it which works in IE and Firefox will be great.